# Reprojection issue while trying to recode an OpenLayers function

Tags: javascript, openlayers, proj4js

Because of conflicts between some libraries (prototype.js and pro4js) i need to rewrite a function of OpenLayers. But even when i try to use the exact same code than on their github, the result differs from the one i get without rewriting the function.

In my case the function in want to recode is `register()` from `ol/proj/proj4`

Here is a reprojection example using this function :

```js
proj4.defs('EPSG:27572', "+title=NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II +proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
proj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27572');

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: proj,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Reprojection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 600px;
        height:400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But then if i recode this function (according to this source : https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/proj/proj4.js), the projection i defined does not have any effect on the ol map except totaly blurring the map ( but i guess this is a side effect of my main problem since blurry maps are most of the time du to reprojection issue ) :

```js
ol.proj.proj4.register = function(proj4) {
    const projCodes = Object.keys(proj4.defs);
    const len = projCodes.length;
    let i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const code = projCodes[i];
        if (!ol.proj.get(code)) {
            const def = proj4.defs(code);
            ol.proj.addProjection(new ol.proj.Projection({
                code: code,
                axisOrientation: def.axis,
                metersPerUnit: def.to_meter,
                units: def.units
            }));
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const code1 = projCodes[i];
        const proj1 = ol.proj.get(code1);
        for (j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            const code2 = projCodes[j];
            const proj2 = ol.proj.get(code2);
            if (!ol.proj.getTransform(code1, code2)) {
                if (proj4.defs[code1] === proj4.defs[code2]) {
                    ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([proj1, proj2]);
                } else {
                    const transform = proj4(code1, code2);
                    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(proj1, proj2, transform.forward, transform.inverse);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

proj4.defs('EPSG:27572', "+title=NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II +proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
proj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27572');

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: proj,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Reprojection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 600px;
        height:400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain to me where i am wrong ? And of course if you have a better idea for rewriting a function from a library i would enjoy it also !

BTW : For curious, the conflict i try to face is because prototype.js adds extra properties to objects. I don't know a lot about this framework and I don't have the hand on it or the choice to remove it. Since the function `ol.proj.proj4.register()` retrieves projection codes with `Object.keys()`, it actually retrieves much more than those codes because of prototype.js. And of course generates an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ol.proj.getTransform` is not the same as `{get as getTransform} from './transforms.js'` (which would be `ol.proj.transforms.get` if it was part of the API).  Since it isn't listed in the public API it isn't available via the full build so you would need to use an alternative test for a transform being defined, or simply don't bother to test and always redefine.

```js
ol.proj.proj4.register = function(proj4) {
    const projCodes = Object.keys(proj4.defs);
    const len = projCodes.length;
    let i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const code = projCodes[i];
        if (!ol.proj.get(code)) {
            const def = proj4.defs(code);
            ol.proj.addProjection(new ol.proj.Projection({
                code: code,
                axisOrientation: def.axis,
                metersPerUnit: def.to_meter,
                units: def.units
            }));
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        const code1 = projCodes[i];
        const proj1 = ol.proj.get(code1);
        for (j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
            const code2 = projCodes[j];
            const proj2 = ol.proj.get(code2);
            //if (!ol.proj.getTransform(code1, code2)) {
                if (proj4.defs[code1] === proj4.defs[code2]) {
                    ol.proj.addEquivalentProjections([proj1, proj2]);
                } else {
                    const transform = proj4(code1, code2);
                    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms(proj1, proj2, transform.forward, transform.inverse);
                }
            //}
        }
    }
}

proj4.defs('EPSG:27572', "+title=NTF (Paris) / Lambert zone II +proj=lcc +lat_1=46.8 +lat_0=46.8 +lon_0=0 +k_0=0.99987742 +x_0=600000 +y_0=2200000 +a=6378249.2 +b=6356515 +towgs84=-168,-60,320,0,0,0,0 +pm=paris +units=m +no_defs");
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
proj = ol.proj.get('EPSG:27572');

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: proj,
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 1
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Reprojection</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/css/ol.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.1.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 600px;
        height:400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer accepted, works like a charm :) could you just explain a case where the test you commented could be necessary ? I did some test with orthers projections and didn't get any problems

Comment: The test improves efficiency by avoiding redoing work already done, so it is useful but not essential.  However OpenLayers has a built in EPSG:4326/EPSG:3857 transform which is slightly different to the proj4 transform https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9836 so you might want to check for those projection to avoid overwriting that,